# Nmap not working when implemented in crontab

Tags: linux, networking, bash, cron, nmap

I am trying to scan the network every day at a particular time(below example at 12:18) by using cronjobs and then output the IPs in a file. The command works perfectly but does not work if implemented in cronjobs. The following is implemented in /etc/crontab:

> 18 12 * * * root /usr/bin/nmap -O 10.0.0.10-253 | grep 'Nmap scan' |
>   cut -d' ' -f5> HostList

Answer (score 0):

The most likely answer when a functional manual command doesn't behave properly when run as a cron job is because something is different when you run the command manually versus when cron spawns the job.  That difference is most commonly that the PATH isn't the same, or the PWD (current directory) isn't the same.

Solve those problems by specifying absolute paths on executables and filenames:

```
18 12 * * * root /usr/bin/nmap -O 10.0.0.10-253 | /bin/grep 'Nmap scan' | /usr/bin/cut -d' ' -f5 > /var/tmp/HostList
```

Those paths are untested examples, chosen for illustrative purposes.  You will need to verify the location of the executables and the desired location of your output file, and adjust the crontab entry accordingly.